# Modify the URL generated with Route::apiResource without changing the name

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-8

I'm building a website where users can post ads : a VueJS app that requests routes on an Laravel API.

I have an AdController, with an Ad model, and my routing is done via stuff like :

```
Route::apiResource('ads', AdController::class)->only(['update', 'destroy']);
Route::apiResource('ads.photos', AdPhotoController::class)->only(['index']);
```

which generates routes like PUT "/ads/{ad}" or GET "/ads/{id}/photos"....

This works very well, and my VueJS app uses Ziggy to call the API by their route name

```
axios.get(route('ads.photos.index', id))
```

And... It still works flawlessly ! No problem at all, and I have a LOT of routes with a LOT of API calls.

Now my problem : we realised that URLs containing "ads" are blocked by adblockers. That completely shuts down all access to our website, and asking users to turn off the adblocker is NOT a solution.

I could change my routes to do something like

```
Route::apiResource('posts.photos', AdPhotoController::class)->only(['index']);
```

but I have a LOT of routes and I really don't want to rename everything, everywhere.

Is there an option to change apiResources generated URL, so 'ads.photos.index' would generate "/posts/{id}/photos" instead of "/ads/{id}/photos" ?

Comment: Not without editing / overriding  some functions in the `Router`. For example the `addRoute` or `createRoute` function. This would probably lead to some undesirable behavior later. It's better just to change all the uris.